# How to get current iteration step in Flink's iterators?

Tags: scala, apache-flink

Is it possible to access the current iteration index when performing iterations in Apache Flink 1.3.2 and Scala 2.10?

```
val initialData: DataSet[(ItemSet[T], Int)]

initialData.iterate(maxIterations) {
    current: DataSet[(ItemSet[T], Int)] =>
        val currentIteration = ??? // Is this accessible somehow?
        // ...
        current
}
```

Based on my search so far, the short answer is "No" and the slightly longer answer is that it may be possible to hack around this using Flink's [raw state](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.3/dev/stream/state.html#raw-and-managed-state).

Answer (score 1):

**Solution # 1:** One way is to write a `system.out.println()` inside this iterator and print values to console, or write those values to  CSV as, but there will be some overhead in these cases.

**Solution # 2:** Another way is to use `Counter` inside a map function which will increment the values and then use `JobExecutionResult` to get this value

Here is how I can be done in Java

---

Let's say I am joining 2 streams and I want to count how many events are getting merged in total.

```
DataStream<Event> mergedStream = stream1.union(stream2);
```

To do this I will write a `map` function which will be called for each merged event and perform an increment using `countername.add(value_to_increment)`.
Also, we have given it a name `merged`, which can be used at the end to fetch the results.

```
 mergedStream.map(new RichMapFunction<Event, Object>() {

            IntCounter counter1 ;

            @Override
            public void open(Configuration parameters) throws Exception {
                super.open(parameters);
                this.counter1 = getIterationRuntimeContext().getIntCounter("merged");
            }

            @Override
            public Object map(Event event) throws Exception {
                counter1.add(1);
                return null;
            }


        });
```

Now, this is how we will get the results. Here `JobExecutionResult` will hold the execution results which can be queried later

```
JobExecutionResult jobExecutionResult = envrionment.execute(" Started the execution ");
```

This is how we get the # of merged events

```
number_of_merged_events = (Integer) jobExecutionResult.getAllAccumulatorResults().get("merged");
```

You can also do `System.out.println();` inside the map to see the values on the console.

Please let me know if you have any further questions